# Paypal ipn/cart variables

Tags: variables, paypal, cart, paypal-ipn

Wondered if anyone could give me any pointers?

The website I'm currently building sells 'event' tickets....holidays.

What I'm trying to do is decrease the number of tickets in a database field by the number purchased BUT can't find a paypal cart variable which will pull the information back. The custom variable it seems can only be used once and the item_name and item_number variables are already being used, the (item_number) to identify the 'event_id' field in the database and the (item_name) to obviously identify the event name.

I can pass the correct number of tickets to be updated over to Paypal by decreasing the amount and echoing that out in a hidden form field prior to sumbitting to Paypal BUT I can't get the results back. I'm looking for a Paypal form 'name' field that can be adapted to my needs, if one exists

Below is the database loop: The 'custom' variable doesn't work as it can't be custom1, custom2 etc.

```
    mysql_connect('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx') or exit(0);
    mysql_select_db('xxxxxx') or exit(0);

$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];



$i=1;
while (isset($_POST['item_number'.$i]))//read the item details
{
$item_ID[$i]=$_POST['item_number'.$i];
$custom[$i]=$_POST['custom'.$i];
$i++;
}

$item_count = $i-1;

for ($j=1;$j<=$item_count;$j++) 

{

$struery = "UPDATE events SET event_tickets = '".$custom[$j]."' WHERE event_id = '".$item_ID[$j]."'";
$result = mysql_query($struery) or die("Cart - paypal_cart_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
$i++;

}// end database loop


Thanks for any info.

Os
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put custom variable as JSON encoded string. Then decode it.

```
$i=1;
$custom = json_decode($_POST['custom], TRUE);
while (isset($_POST['item_number'.$i]))//read the item details
{
    $item_ID[$i] = $_POST['item_number'.$i];
    $custom[$i] = $custom[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Or you can even `base64_encode` it on send to paypal and верут decode it back it you want variable not to be readable when you redirect user to paypal.